# Compression in SQLite database .Net C#

Tags: sqlite, compression

Can BLOB (or any other data) be compressed (on the fly) into an SQLite3 database?
I'm using System.Data.SQLite in C# targeting .net 3.5.

In my search I keep seeing connection strings like so...
"datasource=base.db;version=3;compress=true;"

But I can find no information about compress=true, I've added it to my connection string for testing and added file as BLOB data but there appears to be no compression, I have tested with for example a large text file, so not an already compressed image or other file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my very limited knowledge, the "compress=True" parameter in the System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection String is not taken in account.

Basically, it is kind of useless: there is no built-in compression provided for the .NET System.Data.SQLite.

In order to bring some compression features to the System.Data.SQLite world, you have basically have two options:

- Using some third party tools, whether by including among one of those C libraries and rebuilding the System.Data.SQLite based on it: [Proprietary SQLite Extensions: SEE, CEROD, ZIPVFS](https://www.sqlite.org/support.html#prosupport) / [SQLite Crypt](http://sqlite-crypt.com/) / etc. The commercial ORM Devart based on ADO.NET offers the support for the encryption options I just mentioned and seems they can be used seamlessly (although I personally never tried to use Devart that much).
- Creating a wrapper around the System.Data.SQLite: whether converting all your data with some headers about the encapsulated data are and inserting everything using some collection of bytes with a blob data affinity. You can also by the way provide at the same time some additional encryption process.Of course, this will be (much) slower than the C third-party libraries available and may be not sufficient depending on your requirements (insertions, updates,.., deletions speed), but at least this is free (and time-consuming) approach. This can be achieved through a specific SQLite ORM, should not be that hard to implement but quite time-consuming.

Comment: Thanks, that is quite a comprehensive answer for which I'm very grateful.